# how to fix that fetchmetadata: sill resolvewithnewmodule react-is@16.8.6 checking installable

Tags: reactjs

I am not able to create new project getting this  fetch meta data : sill resolve with new module react-is@16.8.6 checking install . terminal always got stuck on this

Comment: describe your installation process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the command prompt as administrator and it will resolve your problem.